# How to extract data that's in JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, discord

I'm not entirely sure how would I use this json output to list them in python, I mean to loop though them and gather information from the JSON output?

JSON output at: https://hastebin.com/riroteqiso.json
(Data gathered from Ombi API, that uses Traktr as provider.)

Code snippet:

```
request_headers = {'apiKey': pmrs_api_token, 'content-type': 'application/json'}
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
            async with ses.get(pmrs_full_endpoint, headers=request_headers) as response:
                a = await response.json()
                for entry in (a['response']):
                    print(entry)
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sm/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sm/Programming/Python/Discord-Bots/Plex-bot/cogs/ombi.py", line 85, in populartv
    for entry in (a['response']):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

EDIT:

That was fixed by changing it like suggested, but now I have another problem.

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
        async with ses.get(pmrs_full_endpoint, headers=request_headers) as response:
            a = await response.json()
            for entry in a:
                b = await response.json()
                print(type(b)) # Outputs <class 'list'>
                title = (b[entry]['title'])
                first_aired = (b[entry]['firstAired'])
                desc = (b[entry]['overview'])
```

Gives me an error regarding the type again... :/

Comment: That JSON decodes to a Python list of dicts. I assume `a` is a list, so just iterate over that list. You can check by printing `a`, or printing `type(a)`

Comment: @PM2Ring That fixed it, but now I have a another problem.

Comment: Can you give more information on where exactly it caused the problem? And maybe the stacktrace as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your error. You do not need a new b object. The 'entry' variable will contain the element inside the list, in this case it would be the dictionary object inside the list. Therefore you can just extract the value with `entry['title']`.

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
    async with ses.get(pmrs_full_endpoint, headers=request_headers) as response:
        a = await response.json()
        for entry in a:
            title = entry['title']
            first_aired = entry['firstAired']
            desc = entry['overview']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
for entry in (a['response']):
```

By:

```
for entry in a:
```